# D3.js code in Reveal.js slide

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reveal.js

I'm trying to make D3.js work on Reveal.js slides, but I can't get it to run even the most basic snippet:

```
<section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        d3.select("#placeholder").append("p").text("TEST");
    </script>
</section>
```

Doesn't show the "TEST" word. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay here we go.

I have made a basic example with **Reveal.js** & **D3.js** and it works well.

- There are two slides
- First slide contains **Bar chart**
- Second slide renders **Bubble chart** by taking data from a **json input** file

Your code works fine if it is placed **outside** of the **section** at the bottom. I have placed all D3.js code at the end of the html page before body closer.

The folder structure is show below (in snapshot)

[image]

I placed my JS inside the HTML (in order to make it easier to read/comprehend)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Reveal.js with D3 JS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reveal.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme/default.css" id="theme">
        <style>
            .chart rect {
              fill: #63b6db;
            }

            .chart text {
              fill: white;
              font: 10px sans-serif;
              text-anchor: end;
            }

            text {
              font: 10px sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section>
                    <h2>Barebones Presentation</h2>
                    <p>This example contains the bare minimum includes and markup required to run a reveal.js presentation.</p>
                    <svg class="chart"></svg>
                </section>

                <section id="sect2">
                    <h2>No Theme</h2>
                    <p>There's no theme included, so it will fall back on browser defaults.</p>
                    <svg class="bubleCharts"></svg>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/reveal.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            Reveal.initialize();
        </script>

        <script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //------ code to show D3 Bar Chart on First Slide-------
            var data = [44, 28, 15, 16, 23, 5];
            var width = 420,
                barHeight = 20;

            var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
                .range([0, width]);

            var chart = d3.select(".chart")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

            var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
                .data(data)
              .enter().append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

            bar.append("rect")
                .attr("width", x)
                .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

            bar.append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; })
                .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text(function(d) { return d; });


            //---Code below will show Bubble Charts on the secon Slide -------
            var diameter = 560,
                format = d3.format(",d"),
                color = d3.scale.category20c();

            var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                .sort(null)
                .size([diameter, diameter])
                .padding(1.5);

            var svg = d3.select(".bubleCharts")
                .attr("width", diameter)
                .attr("height", diameter)
                .attr("class", "bubble");

            d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
              var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                  .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
                  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
                .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "node")
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

              node.append("title")
                  .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

              node.append("circle")
                  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

              node.append("text")
                  .attr("dy", ".3em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                  .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
            });

            // Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
            function classes(root) {
              var classes = [];
              function recurse(name, node) {
                if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
                else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
              }
              recurse(null, root);
              return {children: classes};
            }

            d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output/results**

**Slide 1**
[image]

**Slide 2**
[image]

**Download complete code** [https://github.com/aahad/D3.js/tree/master/Reveal JS with D3 JS](https://github.com/aahad/D3.js/tree/master/Reveal%20JS%20with%20D3%20JS)

To learn more about how Bar Chart or Bubble Chart code works: check followings:

- Bubble Chart examples: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269
- Bar Chart examples: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

Answer (score 21):

Both existing answers are fine, but I'd like to point out a 3rd approach that worked for me and has some advantages.

Reveal.js has an event system and it also works with the [per-slide data states](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#states).

This means that you can have a separate javascript block for each slide and have it execute only when that slide is loaded. This lets you do D3-based animations upon load of the slide and has the further advantage of placing the code for the slide closer to the text/markup of it.

For example, you could set your slide like this. Note the `data-state` attribute:

```
<section data-state="myslide1">
    <h2>Blah Blah</h2>
    <div id="slide1d3container"></div>
</section>
```

And then have an associated script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Reveal.addEventListener( 'myslide1', function() {

    var svg = d3.select("#slide1d3container").append("svg")
    // do more d3 stuff

} );
</script>
```

Here's an example of a presentation that uses this technique:
http://explunit.github.io/d3_cposc_2014.html

Comment: You can also look here https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/456
This issue give the same  kind of answer.

Comment: Eventually, this still may overload the client if you have many animations of large svg graphics. Is there a way to clear the svg when changing slide back or forth on leaving the current slide?

Answer (score 3):

I found out by myself. Of course I cannot match against ids that are not loaded yet: it works if I put the d3 javascript code after the Reveal.initialize script block at the end of the index.html file.